# kfree_skb() after skb_dequeue() freezes linux kernel

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, network-programming

I'm implementing flow control in a custom protocol in the linux kernel. When I receive an ACK, I want to remove the acked packets from the write queue. Here's some code

```
for(i = (ack->sequence - qp->first_unack); i>0&&sk->sk_write_queue.qlen>0; i++){
    skb_del = skb_dequeue(&sk->sk_write_queue);
    qp->first_unack++;
    kfree_skb(skb_del);
}
```

I get a kernel freeze from this code. Everything works well however, when I comment out the `kfree(skb_del)`. Any ideas why is this happening? How else can I free up the memory?

Comment: can you give the kernel freeze message or kernel crash dump

Comment: The kernel log file doesn't contain anything as the freeze stops the write to the file

Comment: It would be good if you share more context on your source. When you say it works after commenting kfree(), it looks like a double free of skb_del causing this crash.

Answer (score 1):

As the skbs are queued to the socket you can use already provided socket APIs;

```
sk_eat_skb(struct sock *sk, struct sk_buff *skb, bool copied_early)  // copied_ealy = 0
```

For more details you can track tcp_recvmsg, there properly you will get the impementation flow

Moreove why you are using custom APIS from the queuing/dequeuing loop on your own. Just go through the `include/net/sock.h` I hope you will get necessary details

Comment: That is a good idea. but aren't the functions I'm using part of the standard socket API?

Comment: You can go through the include `/linux/skbuff.h` , tere you will get more ideas. Yes the API are standard but linux has provided standard API, like `skb_queue_walk(&sk->sk_receive_queue, skb)`

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because of double freeing `skb_del`.

**Theoretically**, before calling `kfree_skb(skb_del)` you can check the value of `skb_del->users` by doing `refcount_read(&skb_del->users)`, and if `skb_del->users` is 0, then it means that `skb_del` has already been freed.

**In practice**, the `kfree_skb()` function doesn't set `skb_del->users` to 0 when `skb_del` is finally released (due to some optimization considerations), so after `skb_del` will be release it would stay 1, and you won't be able to know if `skb_del` has been released or not.

If you are still curious if this is a double-free issue and you are fine with making some changes in the `skbuff` infrastructure (just for this investigation) then we need to modify some `skbuff` functions.

**WARNING:** It's very easy to cause the kernel to crash when playing with this function, so be careful. But these modification works (in this way I've found a double-free of skb). Keep in mind that this is a suggestion only for investigating the double-free issue, and I've no idea if these modifications will effect your system in the long-run.

We'll modify the following functions (based on kernel v5.9.1):

```
skb_unref()   // from include/linux/skbuff.h
__kfree_skb() // from net/core/skbuff.c
kfree_skb()   // from net/core/skbuff.c
consume_skb() // from net/core/skbuff.c
```

**Original skb_unref()**

```
static inline bool skb_unref(struct sk_buff *skb)
{
    if (unlikely(!skb))
        return false;
    if (likely(refcount_read(&skb->users) == 1))
        smp_rmb();
    else if (likely(!refcount_dec_and_test(&skb->users)))
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

**Modified skb_unref()**

```
static inline bool skb_unref(struct sk_buff *skb)
{
    if (unlikely(!skb))
        return false;   
    if (likely(refcount_read(&skb->users) == 1)) {
        smp_rmb();
        refcount_set(&skb->users, 0);       
    } else if (likely(!refcount_dec_and_test(&skb->users))) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

**Original __kfree_skb()**

```
void __kfree_skb(struct sk_buff *skb)
{
    skb_release_all(skb);
    kfree_skbmem(skb);
}
```

**Modified __kfree_skb()**

```
void __kfree_skb(struct sk_buff *skb)
{
    if (!skb_unref(skb))
       return;

    skb_release_all(skb);
    kfree_skbmem(skb);
}
```

**Original kfree_skb()**

```
void kfree_skb(struct sk_buff *skb)
{
    if (!skb_unref(skb))
        return;

    trace_kfree_skb(skb, __builtin_return_address(0));
    __kfree_skb(skb);
}
```

**Modified kfree_skb()**

```
void kfree_skb(struct sk_buff *skb)
{
    //if (!skb_unref(skb))
    //  return;

    trace_kfree_skb(skb, __builtin_return_address(0));
    __kfree_skb(skb);
}
```

**Original consume_skb()**

```
void consume_skb(struct sk_buff *skb)
{
    if (!skb_unref(skb))
        return;

    trace_consume_skb(skb);
    __kfree_skb(skb);
}
```

**Modified consume_skb()**

```
void consume_skb(struct sk_buff *skb)
{
    //if (!skb_unref(skb))
    //  return;

    trace_consume_skb(skb);
    __kfree_skb(skb);
}
```

Good luck in the investigation.
May god will be with you.